# Do not return back to code from onClickListener onClick method

Tags: java, android

This part of the code is to add 3 `EditText` lines while the button `secbutt` is clicked. While all three `EditText` lines are on the screen, the button should disappear.

Now I do not understand why after entering `onClick` method and starting `plusTextField` method, it just adds `EditText` lines infinitely. I want it to execute once and to return to the beginning of `summonButton` method. What should I do?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numberOfLinesLeft = 3;

    Button secondaryActivityAddButton;

    LinearLayout llForSecondaryButton;

    LinearLayout llForSecondaryEditText;

    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    public void summonButton(View view){

            llForSecondaryButton = findViewById(R.id.secondaryButton);
            secondaryActivityAddButton = new Button(this);

            secondaryActivityAddButton.setText("" + numberOfLinesLeft);
            llForSecondaryButton.addView(secondaryActivityAddButton);

            secondaryActivityAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                    plusTextField();

                }
            });

    }

    public void plusTextField() {

            llForSecondaryEditText = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

            // add edittext
            et = new EditText(this);
            et.setText("text" + numberOfLinesLeft);
            llForSecondaryEditText.addView(et);
            numberOfLinesLeft--;

    }
}
```

ActivityMain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.egrishin.task_a_day.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/main_task_title"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/main_task_line_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="What is 1 main thing to be done today?"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textline2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/secondary_task_title"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="summonButton"
        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            >

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/secondaryButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/other_task_title"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should really get used to naming your variables properly.

Comment: Thanks! Done some edits. Is it better?

Comment: Can you add your layout?

Comment: @LunaVulpo of course, done!

Comment: Please  see my answer below and let me know if it helped

Comment: @MishaAkopov Thank you for your reply! Sorry for the delay, I experienced some problems with my testing environment yesterday. I liked your code, this was the thing I planned to implement. That was not the thing I asked of, but it helped me to move further. So thank you once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss logic of setting the button invisible when counter riches 0 :

```
            public void onClick(View view) {

                plusTextField();

                if(numberOfLinesLeft == 0) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
```

Here is the result, there is no button after adding 3 Edit Texts:

[image]